# inside an elevator falling in an electric field vs a gravitational field - equally oblivious?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, classical-electrodynamics

After reading [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13607/7982) about the gravitational force I wondered how that applied to the electric force, since both have the same basic form - product of the masses or charges over distance squared.

If I was in a charged metal-walled elevator that was "falling" in an electric field, would I be just as oblivious as my friend who was in another elevator falling in a gravitational field?

Comment: I guess so, in the heavily hypothetical world you are describing. But just remember how electric fields different from gravitational fields- there's no such thing as negative mass but there are negatively charged particles. So the "elevator" logic would only apply for positively charged particles, or if the field was reversed it would apply to electrons. Another important fact is that both gravitational fields- and electric fields are conservative; might be a good idea to research that concept too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The acceleration of the elevator would be uniform. But you would not be free floating in it, you would not be accelerated like the elevator if you remain uncharged. You'd be pushed vs the elevator floor (or the ceiling, depends on which way is the E field and the elevators charge. Here I'm just saying floor to be specific). The electric field inside the elevator anyway would be zero if you didn't touch anything (maybe even if you did, have to think about it), so you yourself would not be accelerated by any electric field. You would be pressed against the elevator floor, and  you'd feel the push of the elevator.

If it was not insulated or you touched the elevator walls or floor/ceiling you are always free to insulate it, and still do that experiment where you don't free float. If you touched the elevator and it was no insulated you probably would get to the same voltage as the elevator since you are mostly (but not exactly) conductor, but your charge would depend on your capacitance wrt the elevator.

The key point is that the electric force on you would depend on your charge, which might be minimal, or zero. Not on your mass, like in a gravitational field - the elevator does not insulate you vs a gravitational field, but it does vs an electric field. There is no equivalence principle here, like in gravity. Your acceleration, to stay free floating with the elevator, would depend on your q/m, and the lectromagnetic field inside, i.e., on qE/m, which would have no reason whatever to be the same as the elevator's. You'd hit the elevator and be pushed by it.

But to be really sure, go ahead and calculate qE/m inside based on the m and E outside. If you simplify it so your body is a neutral point particle, you get no q and your acceleration inside is zero. Hit the floor.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for going through it so systematically. Both my near-zero charge in the elevator, and the shielding by dielectric shells and even more effectively metal shells are the consequence of there being two kinds of charge and attraction/repulsion between opposite/like kinds respectively.

Comment: I agree, but the equivalence would still not hold if all charges were negative (not that they can, but just consider). Even if you did build up a charge, and the electric field made it inside the elevator, your q/m would still not be constant. If it were that q is proportional to m (you could then redefine units so q/m =1) it would mean there is no different EM force. And the fact that there is no such equivalence for the electromagnetic field is because the EM field interacts only with charges and the gravitational field gravitational charge is the inertial mass, while q/m is not 1